# Limiting user access to local Gitorious repository

Tags: permissions, git

I have installed and configured in private server a local git repository using Gitorious. The problem I am facing is that when I set up a new Gitorious project and limit read access permissions to specific users, the repositories inside the project are not visible any more.

This happens even though the access permissions of those repositories grant access to these users.

Any idea on how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance!